# Deserialising using Freezed with Generic Type Class

Tags: flutter, dart, generics, freezed, flutter-freezed

Feature for [deserializing Generic Classes](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed#deserializing-generic-classes) was introduced to freeze a few months back.

I am trying to follow the documentation, but I am facing a compile time error:

`The argument type 'NameOfClass Function(Map<String, dynamic>)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'NameOfClass Function(Object?)'.`

Here is a simplified version of my data classes to explain what I am trying to achieve.

### 1. Outer Class

```dart
@Freezed(genericArgumentFactories: true)
class ResponseWrapper<T> with _$ResponseWrapper<T>{
  const factory ResponseWrapper ({
    final String? Status,
    final T? Response,
  }) = _ResponseWrapper;

  factory ResponseWrapper.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json,
      T Function(Object? json) fromJsonT)
    => _$ResponseWrapperFromJson<T>(json, fromJsonT);
}
```

### 2. Inner Class

```dart
@freezed
class NewUser with _$NewUser {
  const factory NewUser({
    String? firstName,
    String? middleName,
    String? surname,
    String? username,
    String? emailId,
  }) = _NewUser;

  factory NewUser.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$NewUserFromJson(json);
}
```

Running the command `flutter pub run build_runner build` runs without any errors and all the red squiggly lines disappear.

### 3. Attempting to deserialize

I am using the following code to deserialize the json.

```dart
const String stringResponse = '{"Status": "Success", "Response": { "firstName": "XYZ", "middleName": "ABC", "surname": "EDF", "username": "abc", "emailId": "abc@gmail.com" } }';

final Map<String, dynamic> encoded = jsonDecode(stringResponse);
final ResponseWrapper<NewUser> newUserWithWrapper = ResponseWrapper.fromJson(encoded, NewUser.fromJson);
```

In the above code block, on the last line's `NewUser.fromJson` I am getting red squiggly line error that says:
`The argument type 'NewUser Function(Map<String, dynamic>)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'NewUser Function(Object?)'.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although I am not sure if it is a better approach, changing the last line to the following solves the problem:

```dart
final ResponseWrapper<NewUser> newUserWithWrapper = ResponseWrapper.fromJson(
      encoded,
      (Object? json) => NewUser.fromJson(json as Map<String, dynamic>));
```